# Cleaning A Large CSV File Efficiently

Tags: python, csv

Problem: I have a CSV file with a large amount of data, and I need to perform some data cleaning and filtering operations on it using Python.

For instance, the CSV file contains a column with dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", but some of the entries have incorrect formatting or missing values. I need to clean up these entries so that they are all in the correct format and remove any rows that have missing dates.

How can I clean and filter a large CSV file using Python with the shortest runtime possible?

```
import csv

# Read the CSV file into a list of dictionaries
data = []
with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

# Loop through the data and clean up the date column
for i in range(len(data)):
    if 'date' in data[i]:
        date = data[i]['date']
        if date:
            try:
                year, month, day = date.split('-')
                year = int(year)
                month = int(month)
                day = int(day)
                if year < 1000 or year > 9999 or month < 1 or month > 12 or day < 1 or day > 31:
                    raise ValueError('Invalid date format')
                data[i]['date'] = f'{year}-{month:02d}-{day:02d}'
            except ValueError:
                del data[i]['date']

# Loop through the data and remove rows with missing dates
clean_data = []
for row in data:
    if 'date' in row and row['date']:
        clean_data.append(row)
```

Comment: I assume it's not possible to ask the source of this data to clean up in their system? I'm just curious, what data source exports data as structured csv but still containing such messy data? Is it copied from an old system or like manually entered data or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the pandas module which enables to handle csv data efficiently in Python. For instance, the following code solves your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Clean up the date column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

# Remove rows with missing dates
df.dropna(subset=['date'], inplace=True)
```

Please note that this does not anylonger check whether your date is in format "YYYY-MM-DD" but in any format which is suitable for dates. Since this is more flexible, it might be an advantage. Otherwise, you can simply modify the code to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

While Pandas is great, if it is about speed, I'd check out things like [Dask, Ray, or Modin](https://www.datarevenue.com/en-blog/pandas-vs-dask-vs-vaex-vs-modin-vs-rapids-vs-ray). The great thing about [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) is that the syntax is the same as Pandas, so if you take @mathbreaker's given Pandas solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Clean up the date column
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

# Remove rows with missing dates
df.dropna(subset=['date'], inplace=True)
```

You can switch to Modin by changing this line:

```py
import modin.pandas as pd
```

This should help a lot if you're working with big datasets:

[image]